# play framework , java, array - model : Take some elements from a view with a ?model class, and make a json array?

Tags: java, arrays, json, class, playframework

Hei guys. This is the first time I am doin' this (*and I'm not really good friends with java*), so I don't know how things work. Hope I can make you understand what I am trying to do, because I need some help.

I have this controller

```
  public static Result AreaDesc(){

            DynamicForm areaData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();

            String url ="http://localhost...";  

            ObjectNode jsonParams = Json.newObject();

            jsonParams.put("image_url", areaData.get("image_url"));
            jsonParams.put("contact_email", areaData.get("contact_email"));
            jsonParams.put("contact_website",areaData.get("contact_website"));


//here is the problem : 

            List<BoothDescription> product = new ArrayList<BoothDescription>();
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                product.add(new BoothDescription(areaData.get("product_id"), 
                                                 areaData.get("product_name"), 
                                                 areaData.get("product_description")
                                                 ));
                array.put(product.get(i));
            }
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("products", array);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Area booth description \n ; json product: "+array);

             WSRequestHolder holder=WS.url(url);
             holder.setContentType("application/json");
             holder.setHeader("Cookie","sessionid="+session("sessionid"));

             WSResponse postResult = holder.post(jsonParams).get(20000);

             System.out.println("Add area booth description status result:" + postResult.getStatus());
             System.out.println("userid:" + session("userid") + "\nsessionid:" + session("sessionid") + " \nJson result: " + jsonParams);


            return ok();

        }
```

I have this Model class. I don't know if I really need to 'extend' it :

```
@Entity
public class BoothDescription extends Model {

    @Id
    String product_id;
    String product_name;
    String product_description;

    public BoothDescription(String product_id, String product_name, String product_description) {

        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_description = product_description;    
      }
...
    }
```

... when I complete this form :

```
Contact Email :
<input name="contact_email" class="form-control">
Contact Website : 
<input name="contact_website" class="form-control">
Image Url:
<input name="image_url" class="form-control">

    Product id :
    <input name="product_id" class="form-control">
    Product Name : 
    <input name="product_name" class="form-control">
    Product Description : 
    <input name="product_description" class="form-control">
```

I want to put my product features in an array:

```
List<BoothDescription> product = new ArrayList<BoothDescription>();
```

make it json:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

and pass it to my server to store it in my  database....

```
 obj.put("products", array);
```

My  `array json product: is null`, that means that the values from my input are not passed to my array... What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but what's the point of adding the object to the `product` list then adding it to the JSON array? Why not just add the new object directly? Also, while it's unimportant, if you *must* do that, why not just create the `BoothDescription` then add it to both collections rather than retrieving it from the `product` list?

Comment: @flori Just use `Json.toJson(yourListofBoothDescription)` (from play.libs.Json)